# reducing table so as to get island

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table :

```
 X    Y    Z     T
 __________________
 A          2             
 B          5                       Z is UNIQUE
 C          8
 A          3
 B          6                     
 A          4
 C          1
```

I want reduce the table to the following one according to Z values;

```
 X    Y    Z     T
 __________________

 A         2           
 A         3                   
 A         4
 B         5
 B         6
```

how can I want construct table as follows ?

difference btw 3 and 2 is 1, and PK, i.e X, are same so take "A 2" and "A 3"

difference btw 4 and 3 is 1, and PK, i.e X, are same so take "A 4" and "A 3"

difference btw 6 and 5 is 1, and PK, i.e X, are same so take "B 6" and "B 5"

how can I do that ?

Comment: X is not a primary key since a primary key is unique by definition

Comment: okey you right; I forget

Comment: What do you mean with `X -> Z` ?

Comment: @ypercube, today I am so stupid. you are right. I have erased

Comment: And you don;t want to keep rows with `Z=1` and `Z=8` beacuse? Maybe because rows with next integer values (0,2 in one case and 7,9 in the other have not the same `X`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableX AS a
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM TABleX AS b
        WHERE b.X = a.X
          AND ( b.Z = a.Z + 1
             OR b.Z = a.Z - 1
              )
      )
```